# Find the $Var(X+Y)$, $f (x,y) = cx^{α−1}(y − x)^{β−1}e^{−y}$

Tags: integration, variance, density-function, covariance, marginal-probability

Let X and U have the joint p.d.f.
$$ f_{X,Y} (x,y) = cx^{α−1}(y − x)^{β−1}e^{−y},   0<x<y<\infty $$
Find the Var(X+Y).

V(X+Y) = V(X) + V(Y) + cov(X,Y)

V(X) = E(x^2)-(Ex)^2

To fine the marginal function of X, fx,
$$ f_x(x) = \int_0^y cx^{α−1}(y − x)^{β−1}e^{−y}  dy $$
$$ = cx^{α−1} \int_0^y (y − x)^{β−1}e^{−y}  dy$$

I struggle from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral bounds are incorrect, Actually,
$$
f_X(x){=\int_x^\infty cx^{\alpha-1}(y-x)^{\beta-1}e^{-y}dy
\\=
cx^{\alpha-1}\int_x^\infty (y-x)^{\beta-1}e^{-(y-x)-x}dy
\\=
cx^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty u^{\beta-1}e^{-u-x}dy
\\=
cx^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\int_0^\infty u^{\beta-1}e^{-u}dy
\\=
c\Gamma(\beta)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}
}
$$where $\Gamma(z)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) of $z$.

**Remark**

From $\int_0^\infty f_X(x)dx=1$, the value of $c$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}$, therefore the PDF of $X$ is equal to
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

In terms of $Z=Y-X$,$$E(f(X)g(Z))=c\int_0^\infty dx f(x)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\int_0^\infty dz g(z)z^{\beta-1}e^{-z}.$$In particular, $X,\,Z$ are independent [Gamma-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) variables, in agreement with @MostafaAyaz's computation of $X$'s marginal distribution. You can then finish as follows:

- Take $f=g=1$ to prove $c=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}$.
- Compute $E(X),\,E(X^2),\,E(Z),\,E(Z^2)$, and hence $V(X),\,V(Z)$. (The above link will tell you the Gamma distribution's variance, but it's worth deriving it if it's unfamiliar, in which case you'll need to know $c$ from the previous step.)
- Since $X,\,Z$ are uncorrelated, $V(X+Y)=V(2X+Z)=4V(X)+V(Z)$.